# Which Array / List should I use to keep an static index?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I usually use `HashMap<Integer, Object>` to keep an array of objects where you can get items by `Integer`.

I'm showing you an example so you can understand.

`HashMap<Integer,String>`:

> [0] - Hello
>   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnDiQ.png) - How are you doing
>   [2] - Bye

So with a HashMap, I can remove items **avoiding the rest moving from their indexes**.

`hashmap.remove(0)`

> [0] - null
>   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnDiQ.png) - How are you doing
>   [2] - Bye

But `HashMap` shouldn't be used for indexes with an `Integer`. So... **Which kind of array should I use to perform actions like the ones I am explaining above?**

Edit: About the part of "shouldn't be used", this is what Android Eclipse is telling me:
[image]

Comment: "But HashMap shouldnt be used for indexes with an Integer." Why?

Comment: Your first half is the answer for second half. Both parts are mutually exclusive :)

Comment: hasMap.size() returns int.

Comment: @R.id.pandacoder So..?

Comment: Which kind of operations are you using the most? On which position are the items that you are deleting?

Comment: If you're on android you can use the built in [sparse array](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html)

Comment: @R.id.pandacoder Why suddenly `size` came in between?

Comment: Isn't the answer you're looking for in the dialog box you shared with us? Have you read it?

Comment: @JBNizet Obviously I did, but my question went a bit further; I wanted to know if there was a better approach, or maybe an explanation why it shouldnt be used in those cases.

Comment: @R.id.pandacoder, you're on the wrong neighborhood.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple Array. They can be pointed by integer. And other than calling remove you can set null to the specific place. If you really want to call remove write your own wrapper method which does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use a simple array of strings.

```
String arr[] = new String[size];
```

Comment: Impossible for me, as I don't know the size.

Comment: use an ArrayList<String> instead.

Comment: If I perform a `remove(index)` the next items in the array, will be moved back 1 position, and as the question states, this is what I don't want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I your indices are dense (no big holes in a range [0..n], the most efficient approach would be to use a plain array of `String`:

```
final String[] lup = new String[3];
lup[0] = "Hello";
lup[1] = "How are you doing";
lup[2] = "Bye";

// to remove elements just set the index to `null`:
lup[0] = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SparseArray** which is similar to `HashMap<Integer,String>`

```
SparseArray<String> arr=new SparseArray<String>();
    arr.put(0, "Hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the total size, then go with Arrays. But if you don't then go with ArrayList.

Now, I don't see a purpose of mapping here.

Hashmap is a Map data structure. Like a list each item that is stored in a hashmap is stored at a particular index. This index is called a hash and it is generated using a hash function. Hash functions accept the object to be stored as an argument and generate a number that is unique to it. Different hashing functions have different trade-offs. A function that is too sparse will use up more space than required(your case). while one that is not sparse enough will suffer from collisions where objects use the same hash.

Further Reading if interested: Look at Android's SparseArray implementation for inspiration.
View the source by downloading AOSP's source code here http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html.
It is highly optimized for integers!

Answer (score 0):

After reading a little bit, I guess the answer is the following:

1.- I can't use plain arrays. Reason: I might not know the final size of it.

2.- Lists doesnt fit, as when you remove an item, the following items fits to the new index. I don't want index move.

**So as a global answer, using HashMap is OK, however using SparseArray is recommended as it is more efficient.**